# How can I split a generic List (of T) based on a property of a list member?

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics, .net-2.0

I have a generic List (of Foo) which contains n objects of Type Foo. One of the properties of Foo is PropertyA. PropertyA can be one of ValueA, ValueB or ValueC. Is there an easy way of splitting this into three seperate Lists, one for ValueA, one for ValueB and one for ValueC?

I can write some code which loops the original list and adds each item to a new list based on the property value but this does not seem to be very maintainable (what if I suddenly get a ValueD for example?)

**EDIT. I should have mentioned that I'm using version 2.0 of the framework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C# with .Net 2.0, I have written (too many times):

```
 //if PropertyA is not int, change int to whatever that type is
Dictionary<int, List<foo>> myCollections =
  new Dictionary<int, List<foo>>();
//
foreach(Foo myFoo in fooList)
{
  //if I haven't seen this key before, make a new entry
  if (!myCollections.ContainsKey(myFoo.PropertyA))
  {
    myCollections.Add(myFoo.PropertyA, new List<foo>());
  }
  //now add the value to the entry.
  myCollections[myFoo.PropertyA].Add(myFoo);
}
//
// now recollect these lists into the result.
List<List<Foo>> result = new List<List<Foo>>();
foreach(List<Foo> someFoos in myCollections.Values)
{
  result.Add(someFoos);
}
```

---

Nowadays, I just write:

```
List<List<foo>> result = fooList
  .GroupBy(foo => foo.PropertyA)
  .Select(g => g.ToList())
  .ToList();
```

Or

```
 ILookup<TypeOfPropertyA, foo>> result = fooList.ToLookup(foo => foo.PropertyA);
```

Answer (score 5):

In C# I would write:

```
  List<List<foo>> result = fooList
    .GroupBy(foo => foo.PropertyA)
    .Select(g => g.ToList())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: +1. Telerik converter says the VB equivalent is `Dim result As List(Of List(Of foo)) = fooList.GroupBy(Function(foo As ) foo.PropertyA).[Select](Function(g As ) g.ToList()).ToList()`

Answer (score 5):

If you want exactly 3 lists for valueA, valueB and valueC (even if one of them is empty):

```
Dim listA = (From x in myList Where x.PropertyA = ValueA).ToList()
Dim listB = (From x in myList Where x.PropertyA = ValueB).ToList()
...
```

Otherwise, use the GroupBy operator as suggested by others.

---

EDIT: Since you are using Framework 2.0, I guess you'll have to resort to your loop idea. A generic algorithm implementing GroupBy shouldn't be too difficult, though. Something along the lines of

```
Dim dic as New Dictionary(Of TypeOfYourValues, List(Of Foo))
For Each e As Foo In myList
    If Not dic.ContainsKey(e.PropertyA) Then
        dic(e.PropertyA) = New List(Of Foo)
    End if
    dic(e.PropertyA).Add(e)
Next
```

Then loop through the values of the dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Enumerable.GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx):

```
var groupings = list.GroupBy(x => x.PropertyA);

foreach(var grouping in groupings)
{
    // grouping.Key is the grouped value

    foreach(var entry in grouping)
    {
        // process
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

See below the C# for the VB.Net version - note that there's one additional class (FooFinder) since there are no anonymous methods in VB.NET, so I needed something to be able to store the match state.

Here's a more "functional" way to accomplish the same thing, but still using C# 2.0 syntax.  Note the important difference from other solutions (looping/dictionaries) is the use of the FindAll method on List, which will iterate over your collection and return all items for which the delegate returns true.
C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SplitList
{
    class Program
    {
        class Foo
        {
            public Foo(string propertyA, int number)
            {
                _propertyA = propertyA;
                _number = number;
            }

            private int _number;

            private string _propertyA;

            public string PropertyA
            {
                get { return _propertyA; }
            }

            public int Number
            {
                get { return _number; }
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo>();
            foos.Add(new Foo("ValueA", 1));
            foos.Add(new Foo("ValueA", 2));
            foos.Add(new Foo("ValueA", 3));
            foos.Add(new Foo("ValueA", 4));
            foos.Add(new Foo("ValueB", 5));
            foos.Add(new Foo("ValueB", 6));
            foos.Add(new Foo("ValueC", 7));
            foos.Add(new Foo("ValueC", 8));
            foos.Add(new Foo("ValueC", 9));

            List<Foo> aFoos = foos.FindAll(delegate(Foo f) { return f.PropertyA == "ValueA"; });
            List<Foo> bFoos = foos.FindAll(delegate(Foo f) { return f.PropertyA == "ValueB"; });
            List<Foo> cFoos = foos.FindAll(delegate(Foo f) { return f.PropertyA == "ValueC"; });
            WriteFoos("ValueA", aFoos);
            WriteFoos("ValueB", bFoos);
            WriteFoos("ValueC", cFoos);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void WriteFoos(string propertyAValue, List<Foo> list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Group {0}:", propertyAValue);
            list.ForEach(delegate(Foo f)
                             {
                             Console.WriteLine("Number:{0}, PropertyA:{1}", f.Number, f.PropertyA);
                             });

        }
    }
}
```

VB.NET:

```
Module Module1

    Class FooFinder
        Public Sub New(ByVal propertyAValue As String)
            Me.PropertyAValue = propertyAValue
        End Sub
        Public ReadOnly PropertyAValue As String
        Function Matches(ByVal f As Foo) As Boolean
            Return (f.PropertyAValue = Me.PropertyAValue)
        End Function
    End Class
    Class Foo

        Public Sub New(ByVal propertyAValue As String, ByVal number As Integer)
            _propertyAValue = propertyAValue
            _number = number
        End Sub

        Private _propertyAValue As String
        Private _number As Integer

        Public Property PropertyAValue() As String
            Get
                Return _propertyAValue
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _propertyAValue = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property Number() As Integer
            Get
                Return _number
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Integer)
                _number = value
            End Set
        End Property
    End Class
    Sub Main()

        Dim foos As New List(Of Foo)
        foos.Add(New Foo("ValueA", 1))
        foos.Add(New Foo("ValueA", 2))
        foos.Add(New Foo("ValueA", 3))
        foos.Add(New Foo("ValueB", 4))
        foos.Add(New Foo("ValueB", 5))
        foos.Add(New Foo("ValueC", 6))
        foos.Add(New Foo("ValueC", 7))
        foos.Add(New Foo("ValueC", 8))
        foos.Add(New Foo("ValueC", 9))

        Dim aFoos As List(Of Foo) = foos.FindAll(AddressOf New FooFinder("ValueA").Matches)
        Dim bFoos As List(Of Foo) = foos.FindAll(AddressOf New FooFinder("ValueB").Matches)
        Dim cFoos As List(Of Foo) = foos.FindAll(AddressOf New FooFinder("ValueC").Matches)

        WriteFoos("ValueA", aFoos)
        WriteFoos("ValueB", bFoos)
        WriteFoos("ValueC", cFoos)
        Console.ReadLine()


    End Sub

    Private Sub WriteFoos(ByVal propertyAValue As String, ByVal list As List(Of Foo))
        Console.WriteLine("PropertyAValue:{0}", propertyAValue)
        For Each f As Foo In list
            Console.WriteLine("Number:{0}, PropertyAValue:{1}", f.Number, f.PropertyAValue)
        Next
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: I like the look of this a lot, converting to VB via Telerik give a compilation error on the word 'Function', any idea how this would translate? (Dim aFoos As List(Of Foo) = foos.FindAll(Function(f As Foo) Do Return f.PropertyA = "ValueA" End Function)

Comment: I've updated my response with a VB.NET version - slightly different because of the lack of anonymous methods/delegates in VB.NET 2.0, but the same basic idea.

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = from foo in list
            group foo by foo.PropertyA;

List<Foo> valueAGroup = query.First(g => g.Key == ValueA).ToList();
List<Foo> valueBGroup = query.First(g => g.Key == ValueB).ToList();
List<Foo> valueCGroup = query.First(g => g.Key == ValueC).ToList();
```

Or you could leave out the `ToList()` calls if an `IEnumerable<Foo>` is good enough.

If it is possible that for a ValueX there are no items for which PropertyA equals ValueX, then `First` will throw an exception. In that case, it's a good idea to do this:

```
List<Foo> valueXGroup = (query.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Key == ValueX) ??
    Enumerable.Empty<Foo>()).ToList();
```

This will give you an empty list instead of throwing an exception.

Comment: Won't this throw if there are no items with ValueA?